# Rails ActionMailer: Does :sendmail work in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form on my site for users to contact me, and on form submission a mailer is delivered. In my config/initializers I have a setup_mail intializer:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "localhost",
  :port                 => 25
}

ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail
```

It works in development. But compared to SMTP servers (like Gmail, where you have :login, :username, :password, etc.) I feel like there are so few settings, so I am wary of whether or not it works in production. Where does `:sendmail` actually send from? For the email I want sent, it's going to use the user email as the sender and my email as the receiver.

Comment: Sendmail is a binary and it's availability depends on what server you are deploying to. In my tests on WebFaction, which has Sendmail available, I haven't been able to get ActionMailer to use it. I've tried in both production and development. As a sanity check, it works fine for local development.